# Checked changed event is not firing for first time in asp.net code behind

Tags: asp.net

In my page checked changed event is not firing for first time after the page load. From second time onwards its working. How to get over from this problem. This is my code:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="displaystatus" AutoPostBack="true"
    OnCheckedChanged="displaystatus_CheckedChanged" 
    Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Opt_In__c").ToString() == "False" ? false : true %>'
```

Comment: How are you determining it's not firing? Have you checked your browser console?

Comment: Check does not change when the page loads, only when it is changed by user. ? What are we missing?

Comment: I have placed a debugger in my code behind file because its server side programming. After the page load when I checked the checkbox its not hitting in that time page is loading again. From second time its firing and its working properly